# Rails 3.1 - route redirect based on params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm refactoring an app that has a bunch of urls coming like:

`/plans/1?action=confirm&email=nobody@email.com`

I'd like to redirect them, in routes.rb, to:

`/plans/1/confirm?email=nobody@email.com`

I've tried a number of approaches listed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/ but am not having much luck.

I'm thinking that, because the `action` is after the `?` I need to just do this in the controller.  Is that the case?

Comment: These `confirm` actions, do they come from some gem? Or is it custom code?

Comment: Since they are after the ?, they are already params.  I don't know if it's possible.  You may have to use the redirect_to in the controller as suggested below.

Comment: Sergio - the previous owner of the code put everything in one controller and made calls like this.  We're just breaking up it up now.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to do in the controller.

Since `redirect_to` can take a Hash and turn it into a URL via `url_for`, I think this is what you want.